# What are these two DIN-mounted components in my conveyor belt control panel?

Tags: motor-controller

I am inspecting inside my conveyor belt's control panel.

What are the components circled in blue? It reads "SF-10" on the transparent case, and appears to have a resistor (?) in it.

[image: Inside my conveyor belt's control panel]

Comment: Those look a lot like fuseholders.

Comment: The resistor is probably for an indicator lamp, which illuminates when the fuse opens.

Comment: Probably about 120k to 180k in series with a neon bulb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suddenly thought of using photo searches. It appears it is a fuse holder.
[image: Fuse Holder]

Comment: Given that they have resistors in, and are transparent, would they be fuse holders with small lamps in to indicate when they have blown?